# Generate Static Ionic Output

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created an Ionic application.  I really like using the `ionic serve --lab` option to view Android and iOS versions side-by-side in my browser.  However, I'd like to generate a static version of my files, remove http requests, hard code some data (what was in the requests), and host the static files (in AWS S3, but that's irrelevant).  Is there any way I can do this?  Thank you!